# What are the tax consequences of loaning securities to one's broker aside from the dividends being paid as payment-in-lieu taxed as income?

Tags: united-states, stocks, capital-gains-tax, broker, security-lending

I'm trying to understand the tax consequences of loaning securities to one's broker in the United States:

1. The dividends of the loaned security are being paid as [payment-in-lieu, which is taxed as income](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/127145/5656).
2. Long-term capital gains/losses made on the loaned security will [not](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/135675/5656) be turned into short-term capital gains/losses.

Is there any other tax consequences of loaning securities to one's broker aside from the dividends being paid as payment-in-lieu taxed as income?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're also being paid interest for the loan, and you may lose the securities if they never get back to you, only getting the 102% coverage the insurance provides (which leads to realizing gain/loss when you may not have intended to).